# jQuery Filter Allowed Parameters

Tags: jquery

Is there documentation that provides/explains all possible jQuery filter parameters allowed?

Some of the examples I have seen are :first and :last - are there any more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Those are just the built in ones, though. You can actually create your own!

So if you wanted to get all `<div>` elements that satisfied a certain criteria through a filter, you could do:

```
$.expr[':'].big = function(e) {  
    return $(e).width() > 500;
};
$('div:big'); // would only select divs that are over 500 pixels wide
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I trying to apply the following filtering using the jQuery Scrollable plugin, i.e:

  var itemToRemove = api.getItemWrap().filter("#slot" + ptabIndx);
  itemToRemove.remove();

where slot is defined as follows but it can't seem to find it, i.e:

<a class="" href="2">
<div id="slot2">

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll notice that the selector for your "slot" is ("#slot" + ptabIndx) - when ptabIndx is given a value, such as "2" the selector then effectively becomes ("#slot2") which targets your <div id="slot2">

Comment: As you're starting from a wrapper (aka parent) you probably want to be using `find` instead of `filter`.